# call member function out of Yii?

Tags: php, yii, opencart

I know it's not legal, and looking odd. But it's necessary for me.
I have two projects, one is custom Open-Cart, and the second is in Yii. My main project is opencart. My Yii project is kept in the Main project root.

Now I want to call a Yii function in my open cart.
please anyone help me and tell How to call the Yii function in my main project?

this is my Yii function:-

```
   $sm=Yii::app()->getSecurityManager();

    if ($salt === null)
        $salt = Yii::app()->params['password_security_salt'];
    if($salt==null)
        $salt=md5 (mt_rand ().mt_rand ().mt_rand ().mt_rand ());
    $pass=sha1($salt.$pass.$salt);
    return $sm->hashData($pass,$key).':'.$salt;
```

.....................

I want to create a new function manually for my opencart project.
please help me for creating a new project for the same functionality as Yii (upper function) function.

Comment: You can create action in Yii's some controller which returns your hashed data, and then run url which is pointing to this action. But this solution obviously need to be secure!

Answer (score 2):

You can use Yii functionality outside of the Yii project by initialising the application like so:

```
// this is in someotherfile.php outside of the yii project
require_once('framework/yii.php');
$config = require_once('protected/config/main.php');
Yii::createWebApplication($config);


// call your function
Yii::app()->getSecurityManager();
```

Obviously the paths to the `yii.php` file and the application config (`main.php`) will need to change to fit your project structure

Comment: I try but it's given error, error is :-   Use of undefined constant ROOT_PATH - assumed 'ROOT_PATH'

error in :- /config/main.php file

'appFilesUrl'=>ROOT_URL.'/appmedia', in this line

Comment: Where are you defining `ROOT_PATH`? Inside Yii or inside open cart?

Comment: Ah ok, you'll have to define it again when do the above in open cart, so just add `define('ROOT_PATH',"your/root/path");` at the top. I imagine you'll have to tweak the path

Comment: sir Hardly thanks for your help. but now it's given warning like :=>  Warning[2]: include(CWebApplication.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory